# How do I send the linked list as a function argument

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

<DBDLinkedList.h>

```
...
typedef struct _dbDLinkedList
{
        Node * head;
        Node * tail;
        Node * cur;
        int numOfData;
} DBDLinkedList;

typedef DBDLinkedList List;
...
```

<mysourcecode.c>

```
int main(void)
{

        ...
        List list;
        int data;
        ListInit(&list);

        for(i=0; i<ID_LEN; i++)
                LInsert(&list, new_id[i]);

        solution(list, data);
        ...
}

int solution(List list, int data)
{
     ...
     if(LFirst(&list, &data))
     {
            int i=1;

            if(data==46)
                    LRemove(&list);

            i++;

            while(LNext(&list, &data))
            {
                   if(i==numOfData)
                          if(data==46)
                                 LRemove(&list);

                   i++;
            }
     }
     ...
      
}
```

I used dummy node doubly linked list.
When I complied this project, error occurred :
‘numOfData’ undeclared (first use in this function).

I'm not used to using Linked list.
How do I send the linked list as a function argument(for solution())?

Answer (score 0):

from what I could see, the problem might not be in sending the linked list as a function argument. In "if(i==numOfData)", you are trying to access the numOfData, which is a part of a 'List' structure, so you need to access it through 'List' variable.... Perhaps replacing that line of code with something like "if(i == list.numOfData)" will do the trick

Comment: You're my savior. Thank you very much.

Comment: erehwyrevemai, if this is the answer you were looking for, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`numOfData` is not a variable. You most probably intended to access the current node's `numOfData` member.

But you really don't need to access that member directly. It seems likely (without seeing the code) that `LNext` will put that value in your `data` variable -- it is the reason why you pass `&data` as argument to `LNext`.

This brings us to another issue in your code. You call `solution` with `data`, but you never gave `data` a value. If the intention is to remove the node with value 46, then the main program should call `solution` as follows:

```
solution(list, 46);
```

And `solution` should be implemented as follows:

```
int solution(List list, int dataToRemove) {
    if (!LFirst(&list, &data)) {
        return 0;  // to indicate that value to delete was not found
    }
    while (data != dataToRemove) {
        if (!LNext(&list, &data)) {
            return 0;  // to indicate that value to delete was not found
        }
    }
    LRemove(&list);
    return 1; // to indicate success
}
```

Comment: 'value 46' is  just one of conditions. I didn't upload my all code, so it has deficient information. Your comment isn't perfectly fit on my code, but I really appreciate your advice. Thank you, trincot!

Comment: It was the best I could do with the info provided. If your question is not answered, then maybe you could edit your question and add the other pieces of info. For instance, it is not clear how the uninitialised `data` value that you pass as argument to `solution` is of any use.